# Getting an error saying: TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to connect to a new database ive made inside MongoDB. I'm pretty new to Mongo Db and gatsby so i wanted to know if i was doing something wrong or missing something? Im currently working with the regular gatsby stack JS & graphql

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster.hyqcz.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority)
```

This is the error
`TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function`

Ive tried using `Import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'` to the same result

Answer (score 0):

Can you try use this one?

Was facing same thing - this works for me.

```
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

Comment: ```'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files.ts``` is the error i get when i do that